# Heroku failing to bind PORT

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

```js
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const path = require("path")
const cors = require('cors')
const ical = require('ical-generator')

require('dotenv').config()




const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const HOST = process.env.YOUR_HOST || '0.0.0.0'

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}))
// app.use(bodyParser.json())
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(express.json());

app.use(cors())

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use("/react-portofolio/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")));
}








app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
});
  


// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

// app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
//     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
// });
  






app.listen(PORT, HOST, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://${HOST}:${ PORT }/`)
})
```

Sorry to bother. Similar question has been posted. However I have followed the instruction on 3 different forum but getting the same error when I push to heroku for deployment. Build succeeded but I get something already running on PORT

```
2020-12-08T04:17:26.884688+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] Something is already running on port 57232.
2020-12-08T04:17:27.006588+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm run client exited with code 0
2020-12-08T04:26:37.127662+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=discoversamir.herokuapp.com request_id=46d76b48-2724-4726-9db0-6a7e32aebfc3 fwd="70.119.31.93" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=48ms status=200 bytes=2779 protocol=https
2020-12-08T04:26:37.237894+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.9a72c1e7.chunk.css" host=discoversamir.herokuapp.com request_id=2d0792e3-4cd4-4a05-a2a4-acc41070767d fwd="70.119.31.93" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=14ms status=200 bytes=2779 protocol=https
2020-12-08T04:26:37.239633+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.2cea4fb7.chunk.js" host=discoversamir.herokuapp.com request_id=dfd7e060-3da6-4073-80cd-7499cf41456a fwd="70.119.31.93" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=16ms status=200 bytes=2779 protocol=https
2020-12-08T04:26:37.312361+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/src/App.css" host=discoversamir.herokuapp.com request_id=739a09b6-4f5b-41e8-9c8a-fb05fd183303 fwd="70.119.31.93" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=200 bytes=2779 protocol=https
2020-12-08T04:26:37.313463+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.dff0b724.chunk.js" host=discoversamir.herokuapp.com request_id=2e3abec9-f772-4bc8-b74b-75016552c304 fwd="70.119.31.93" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=14ms status=200 bytes=2779 protocol=https
2020-12-08T04:26:37.399704+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=discoversamir.herokuapp.com request_id=921c7d52-76e6-4254-a9ab-cd8968dd8182 fwd="70.119.31.93" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=2779 protocol=https
2020-12-08T04:26:37.556042+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=discoversamir.herokuapp.com request_id=c58d231d-60c0-42e4-a714-30a20333a156 fwd="70.119.31.93" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=2779 protocol=https
```

Here is my pacakage.JSON

```json
"name": "react-portofolio",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "My portofolio",
"main": "server.js",
"scripts": {
 
  "predeploy": "npm run build",
  "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "if-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run start:prod || npm run start:dev",
  "start:prod": "node server.js",
  "start:dev": "concurrently \"nodemon --ignore 'client/*'\" \"npm run client\"",
  "client": "cd client && npm run start",
  "install": "cd client && npm install",
  "build": "cd client && npm run build",
  "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
},
"repository": {
  "type": "git",
  "url": "git+https://github.com/agnide4/react-portofolio.git"
},
"keywords": [
  "portofolio",
  "resume"
],
"author": "Samir Bello",
"license": "ISC",
"bugs": {
  "url": "https://github.com/agnide4/react-portofolio/issues"
},
"homepage": "https://github.com/agnide4/react-portofolio#readme",
"dependencies": {
  "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
  "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
  "cors": "^2.8.5",
  "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
  "express": "^4.17.1",
  "ical-generator": "^1.15.2",
  "nodemailer": "^6.4.16",
  "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "gh-pages": "^3.1.0"
},
"engines": {
  "node": "12.8.0",
  "npm": "6.14.9"

}
```

It keeps giving me a manifest.JSON error`.
repo is https://github.com/agnide4/react-portofolio . Please point me to the direction of what I am missing.

Comment: "Something already running" suggests that you're binding to the port in two different places. Are you using that variable anywhere else? Do you have a `Procfile`? If so, what does it contain?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this in your server.js file

```js
app.listen(PORT, HOST, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})
```

This, And also try removing the HOST declaration and process.env.HOST

```js
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})
```

Comment: Thanks Saran. I had it the way you suggested and it was giving me the same error. Then I changed it to 0.0.0.0 following heroku dev center suggestions

Comment: Great then happy Coding :)

Comment: it still is not working. I just cleared my cache and try on a different computer and that error keeps coming back. If you have any other suggestion  please let me know.

Comment: Hey i see that your Proc file is mentioning npm start, rather try using node server.js,
And also use the flags to build your react app, rather using if else conditions there, use them in your server.js file and alter them

Comment: And @SamirB if you are only using a node js build back you don't need a proc file also, and also make sure that the node js build back is added to the heroku project

Answer (score 0):

Heroku assigns ports dynamically to your Node process. This should be available for use in `process.env.PORT` — if you want to have a default for running when none is set (ex. `8000`) I'd make sure that your code is doing something like:

```js
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000
```

and then passing `port` to your `app.listen` function.

Comment: @rb6112 that is how I have it. I just added my server.js to the post. App runs locally but not on heroku. Been on this for 72hrs and have tried all kind of code combinations